# What happened to cycles render devices in 3.0 for Linux?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, interface

Was really excited for the 3.0 update... It just updated today and
still no change here. What happened to the Optix option? My brand new RTX 3060 GPU is sad that it can't help.

Current version 3.0.0-2, running in Manjaro Linux. CPU: i5-11400 GPU: GeForce RTX 3060

[image: Screen cap of preferences showing Cycles Render Devices]

Comment: Very disappointed to find out it is all okay in Windows.... I really don't want to have to work in Windows...

Comment: Hi, I am not 100% sure but there was some issue between blender 3.0.0 and linux, I know that it is currently not supporting gpus with linux os but thankfully you will get issue resolved soon, did you try 3.1.0 if there is any chance?

Comment: There definitely seems to be a problem with the Linux version 3.0.0. I will take a look into it and see if I can get 3.1 installed.

Comment: And the 3.1 alpha developer version in the Arch repos looks good... Optix is an option again and it sees my GPU.... and it definitely renders at a good speed. How sketchy will it be to use this version as far as stability is concerned?

Comment: 3.1 may still have some bugs that are not known, that is basically the only one issue, it is stable, just some function may not work and if you find something not working in 3.1, let developers know about it... also there may be new things such as new geometry nodes or that are not in 3.0 or were removed from 3.0

Comment: Thanks so much, Miko. I really appreciate your input. Although I have played around with Blender for many years, I only recently got serious about it. I will definitely put the effort into helping find anything I can.

Comment: You probably have a drivers issue, this happens to me once because the Driver was not the correct one, make sure to use proprietary, tested, even the GTX got support for Optix in linux. For me, a new system installation solved the problem.

Comment: Not sure it would be a driver issue if the 3.1 version is working. I have pretty up to date drivers installed. I see there is a newer one from Nvidia that was put out 5 days ago. Maybe when that gets into the update queue I can go back and try 3.0.

Comment: There's issues with how Blender is installed.  This happens on every Linux distribution depending on how you install Blender. If this happens, uninstall & use: sudo snap install blender --classic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Manjaro just like me. The Problem is not the actual NVidia Driver but rather the compiled Manjaro version of Blender from the Manjaro repository.
It seems to be a legal issue:
[Link to Arch Bugreport](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/72921)

The simplest solution is to download Blender from Blender.org (for Linux) and extract it in to a folder. You can then simply start Blender from there and it will have Optix enabled. It works fine on my machine.

Comment: Works as you said. Thanks so much for that info.